# How I can delete a specific value from UserDefault after 1 hour on Swift

Tags: swift

I want to delete the value from UserDefault after 1 hour because I save some URLs in that’s, so this URL is valid for 1 hour.

Comment: You can't really. What you can do is save a `Date()` for the end validity and a `URL`. Both in a Dict/custom struct.

Comment: Can you make an example for it and how delete it after 1 hour, Also, every single url have an id, and the id it’s fixed